# Flutter and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, aqueduct

Excuse me asking maybe silly/dumb

I'm Rookie self-taught developer

I trying to get my **flutter app to work with my PostgreSQL database**

Unforturnly I couldn't find anything related to Getting Flutter and postgreSQl to work togeather

All I can find is using Aqueduct a dart package which I was not able to install

https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-crud-with-postgresql-part-1-57d8d3652a31

as they couldn't find a library to install Aqueduct

Is there any other way I could get Flutter work with PostgreSQL?

Or there a way I could get Aqueduct to work?

Greatly appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 3):

For interaction of your app with a relation db you need a backend, in any technology, as the negotiator of both parties.I dont know aqueduct but you can try node js + express js as it is a popular backend stack, here a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9) is quite simple to understand and setup, theres is also a js postgresql package called [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) so you will need to add it to your node backend. I don't know how much knowledge do you have about http request/response, backend, frontend or http apis, so you should maybe study all of that before doing your project.

Comment: Thank you Lino, to my understanding I should use Node js + express JS as my backend instead of dart (the language that makes flutter).

Comment: yes, but is not the only option, there is a lot of backend frameworks and technologies, i mentioned node + express as it is one of the most popular, but there are tons of other options, for java spring boot, for php laravel, for python django, etc. and anyone can be useful. Use the one you feel more confident whit it. I dont recommend using aqueduct, it is not that much popular and i dont think it will be as stable as other more mainstream options